# I can't use the contents of the bits/stdc++.h header file on vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code, visual-c++, include, mingw

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    cout << "working..";
}
```

identifier "cout" is undefined.
I get the above error message when trying to use cout.

I am able to compile the above program using gcc but not using msvc.

I have copied the bits folder from mingw and pasted it into the include folder in visual studio code.

I have also tried to paste C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/include into the includePath of the c_cpp_properties.json file.

Comment: There is no such header in C++. Perhaps the source you are learning C++ from is of low quality.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: Plus a bit of [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/21105992) for the second line of the program.